# Hide the nav menu(active) when you click outside of the menu in shopify

Tags: jquery

I been struggling here when clicking outside of menu it should close the menu and the icon close will change to hamburger icon again.

here the code of closing. It looks like a Jquery but I'm not use to this kind of Jquery coding

```
function closeMobileNav() {
cache.$mobileNavContainer.prepareTransition().removeClass(classes.navOpen);

cache.$mobileNavContainer.css({
  transform: 'translate3d(-100%, 0,  0)'
});
cache.$pageContainer.removeAttr('style');

cache.$mobileNavContainer.one('TransitionEnd.navToggle webkitTransitionEnd.navToggle transitionend.navToggle oTransitionEnd.navToggle', function() {
  slate.a11y.removeTrapFocus({
    $container: cache.$mobileNav,
    namespace: 'navFocus'
  });
});

cache.$mobileNavToggle
  .addClass(classes.mobileNavOpenIcon)
  .removeClass(classes.mobileNavCloseIcon);

$(window).off('keyup.mobileNav');       
}
```

it's a code of changing the icon

```
cache.$mobileNavToggle
.addClass(classes.mobileNavOpenIcon)
.removeClass(classes.mobileNavCloseIcon);
```

and this is the code when closing the nav.

```
   cache.$mobileNavContainer.prepareTransition().removeClass(classes.navOpen);
```